# How to convert complex dynamic json to pojo class

Tags: java, pojo

I have below json

```
[{
    "Maindata": "{\"SubData\":[{\"Name\":\"a\",\"rollnumber\":1,\"ParentName\":c},{\"Name\":\"b\",\"rollnumber\":2,\"ParentName\":d},{\"Name\":\"m\",\"rollnumber\":3,\"ParentName\":n}],\"schooltime\":123213,\"lunchtime\":2321,\"TeacherName\":\"abc\",\"ClassTeacherName\":\"abc\",\"Subjects\":null,\"ClassName\":\"xyz\",\"PrincipleName\":[\"sdffd\"],\"ClassID\":\"21312\",\"books\":\"\",\"classdata\":{\"scienceclass\":\"2hrs\",\"Projects\":\"True\",\"Games\":\"Nothing\"},\"real\":null,\"classuniqueid\":\"21323234234\",\"schoolbelltime\":21323321}"
}]
```

In above Json we have

MainData - Main data has two main sections

```
SubData
ClassData
```

When i tried to view the above Json viewer it displays MainData as main Json and doesnot display sub data json

Now i want to convert above json to Pojo class, in a way say if i give Name of Subdata as "a" it should give me all details of "a". Now Subdata is dynamic, it has three sections now, it can have 100 when new students data are available or it can have only two. How to write a pojo class which reads this and gives data.

I am using gson and Below is my pojo class

```
public class MyPojo
{
    private String Maindata;

    public String getMaindata ()
    {
        return Maindata;
    }

    public void setMaindata (String Maindata)
    {
        this.Maindata = Maindata;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [Maindata = "+Maindata+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to show the actual pojos as well as tell us which library you are using to parse the json.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to convert JSON data to POJOs and POJOs to JSON data. 
For complex JSON data like yours, you will need to create ArrayLists of complex types in your corresponding classes.

Answer (score 0):

Paste your valid JSON into this [site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and select

**Target language: Java**

**Annotation Style: GSON**

and download the Zip file, extract it after that you get all POJO classes of your JSON response